# PHP PDO: how to prevent javascript and html tags injection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xss, html-entities

I am using following script to update some data in MYSQL table, for that i am taking data from user. But it is not preventing from javascript and html tags.

```
$attri= //containing field name like ("name=?, email=?")
$value= //containing corresponding values like ("john", "email@exam.com")

$sql_pro = "UPDATE regist SET ".$attri." WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id'];
        $stmt_pro = $db->prepare($sql_pro);
        $i=1;
        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
            $stmt_pro->bindValue($i,$v, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $i++;
        }
        $stmt_pro->execute();
        if($stmt_pro){
            return true;
        }
```

How can i  prevent from javascript and html tag injection?

**Update**
Is there any good way to sanitize input field data before adding into database in PHP PDO.

I know how to do it with mysql_real_escape_string, htmlentities and strip_tags.
thanks

Comment: the code is not really relevant to the issue that you are having. On the display side just echo the database content through htmlspecialchars and you should be good.

Comment: @Let'sCode I am new with PDO. I only know about ‎mysqli_real_escape_string and htmlentities

Comment: what about doing a strip_tags() with your values...

Answer (score -1):

You need proper form input validation and output escaping. Use `htmlspecialchars()` when you display your string.

As far as sanitizing input, `strip_tags` is the quck n' dirty way to do what you want but a much better practice is to make a list of characters that are allowed and use regex to validate.

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', $username)) {
    //Contains a character not in A-Z,0-9, or underscore
} else {
    //Username is fine
}
```